# Problemas con el método bind()

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy teniendo problemas con el método `.bind()`. Soy bastante nuevo en python... Por lo que tengo entendido, se utiliza para que cuando ocurra algo (como un clic o se presione una tecla) se llame a una función, pero al ponerlo en práctica y presionar "enter" me salta `TypeError: event() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` y que yo sepa no le estoy pasando ningún argumento... Aquí esta mi programa:

```py
from tkinter import *
    
ventana = Tk()
    
def event():
    print("hola")
    
ventana.bind("<Return>", event()
    
ventana.mainloop()
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Siempre se le pasa un parámetro por defecto, que es la acción. Es como un `addEventListener` de JS

Answer (score 3):

A Tu función `event()` no le estas pasando un argumento `event` y eso es lo que provoca la excepción, el argumento `event` es necesario para detectar cuando estas presionando una tecla, tu función debería quedar así:

(yo le cambiaria el nombre a la función)

```
def event(event):
    print("Hola")
```

En el método `bind` le estas pasando la función con los paréntesis y eso lo que hace es llamar y ejecutar la función, lo que deberías hacer es esto:

```
ventana.bind("<Return>", event) <- sin paréntesis
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!! Problema solucionado

Comment: Si es la solución podrías aceptar su respuesta :)